# Put an image from web on <input type="hidden">

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, xmlhttprequest

I need to send one specific image in a form. I mean, there isn't a file picker. I need to use a hidden input to save an image like example.com/myimage.jpg and send it to the form like any other file. I can't change the backend.

```js
var img = new XMLHttpRequest();
img.open("get","favicon.ico",false);
img.send();
document.getElementsByName("image")[0].value=img.response;
//This doesn't work
//The image isn't handle like it does with other files
```

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="image" type="hidden" value="IMAGE-HERE">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54413227/put-an-image-from-web-on-input-type-hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021526/programmatically-set-the-value-of-a-type-file-input-html-element)

It was not possible to set file input value programmatically in the past, but it is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515232/how-to-set-file-input-value-when-dropping-file-on-page) now

Answer (score 0):

With Input type hidden, you can pass data for example say a string like name, age or URL. However to upload a file, What you can try is to use

```
<input type="file" name"image" id="image" />
```

and then in your style try to hide the image

```
#image{
visibility : hidden;
}
```