# Append files stored in array to HTML file input [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm creating a jQuery drag and drop upload. I've created everything perfectly so far and stored the files in an array.

Here's the final step:

```
$('.single-product form.cart').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.table(files);

        $('.wcfu-validation').hide();

        var filetypes = ['image/png'];

        $.each(files, function(key, value, e){
            if($.inArray(value.type, filetypes)){
                $('.wcfu-validation').show();
            } else {
                $('input[type="file"]').prop('files', files);
            }
        });
    });
```

Here I'm checking to see if the uploaded file(s) is in the accepted file types array, if it is, then we can loop through each file in the `files` array and append to the HTML `file` input.

However, I'm getting this error:
[image]

Here's what my array looks like as an example if I upload 2 PNG files:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question already has an answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021526/programmatically-set-the-value-of-a-type-file-input-html-element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)